# Medium term repair for cracked shower pan

Tags: repair, shower

The following crack appeared in our shower pan today when I stepped there:

[image]

I need a fix that will last 12-18 months until we re-model the bathroom, and I don't really care how it looks. This location is about half way between the drain and the wall. The pan is sitting on the concrete house foundation (no basement). Several other locations feel like they also have too much give to them.

Would a shower pan inlay be enough to fix that for a few months? Does that crack require a fiberglass repair kit to support and spread out the load? Both?

Looking for suggestions. Due to COVID19 and a high risk individual I need something I can do now, myself, without calling someone in.

Comment: just flex-seal the heck out of it; works for anything according to the commercial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Materials Needed**

- A sheet of something to act as a patch (FRP, acrylic, etc.)
- Good two-part epoxy
- Sandpaper (150-220 grit, maybe)

**Procedure**

1. Cut a patch to the desired size. It should overlap the crack a fair bit to act as a gusset.
2. Trace the patch on the tub with a pencil. Optionally mask outside the patch area to protect that surface.
3. Scuff the patch area with the sandpaper to clean it and rough it up. Also scuff the patch sheet if it's not already rough.
4. Bond the patch to the tub with the epoxy. Finger out the epoxy that squeezes out to create a short taper and seal the edge.
5. Ease the edges of the patch with sandpaper to prevent injury.

You could also do an old airplane mechanic's trick to stop the crack from growing first: Drill a 1/8" or 3/16" hole at the ends of the crack. This distributes force over a wider area.